# Global static variables using Thread vs using Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

Let's say I have a FormWithLabel (just form with a label to show status of current long-term operation) which I show in case of some "heavy" tasks running in my main application form. For this purpose I have static variable:

```
public static FormWithLabel loadingForm = null;
```

I case of "heavy" tasks I create FormWithLabel in separate thread an show it until log operation ends. When I use Thread - it's ok:

```
Thread loadingFormThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        loadingForm = new FormWithLabel();
        loadingForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    ));

    loadingFormThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    loadingFormThread.Start();
...
//some "heavy" work which is done separate thread and updates some visual data in main UI via Invoke()
...
if (loadingForm != null)
    {
        loadingForm.Dispose();
        loadingForm = null;
    }
```

But when I use Task instead of Thread

```
new Task(() =>
    {
         loadingForm = new FormWithLabel();
         loadingForm.ShowDialog();
    }).Start();
...
//some "heavy" work which is done separate thread and updates some visual data in main UI via Invoke()
...
if (loadingForm != null)
    {
        loadingForm.Dispose();
        loadingForm = null;
    }
```

loadingForm is **NULL** at the end of "heavy" work - so **.Dispose()** is never called.

What is the difference between Thread and Task?

Why my static variable remain global in first case and look like it's local for Taks's thread in second case?

Comment: You are breaking just about every rule in the book.  The task just makes it worse, it is not STA.  Only ever do this if you [understand how to do this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  Do this the **correct** way, the "heavy work" must be done on a worker thread, always keep the UI thread available to display and update UI.

Comment: Most part of the approach witt Thread was copied from that [Telerik sample](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/forms-and-dialogs/details/add-splashscreen-to-your-application)

Comment: Splashscreens are normally pretty innocent, they just display a bitmap and don't use controls that use the SystemEvents class.  Like Label.  Just arbitrarily omitting the Invoke() call that closes the window is also a major mistake.  Threading bugs like this are *very* hard to debug.  Don't do it.

Comment: Ok, let's imagine my FormWithLabel has nothing but a picturebox in it. What does it change in behavoir described in my question? Threads still work correctly, but Tasks - not.. And BTW - where do you see Invoke() call in my code sample above?

Comment: You have not described sensible behavior or posted code that could ever repro this behavior.  Make this a *property* instead so you can set a breakpoint on the setter, now it is easy to find out how it got set back to null.  The point about the Invoke() call is that it is *missing* from your snippet, it is not missing in the Telerik sample.  Very, very bad.

Comment: Better way would be to create your `FormWithLabel` from main UI thread (no task or thread) and then use task or thread to do the heavy work and may be use `Invoke` to update UI from your heavy work.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, i've really forgot that Invoke of loadingForm.Close(). My mistake. BTW: why splashForm.Dispose() is called direclty in Telerik sample? Shouldn't it be called via Invoke as well?

Comment: @HansPassant Some strange behavior: when I change loadingForm from variable to property as yuo suggested - loadingForm now is null at the end and all logic works. Why? Some complier optimisations have gone?

Comment: @Honza heavy work in my app is doing exactly as you described (i've update my question for more clearance). I cannot create FormWithLabel in main UI thread because I use .ShowDialog() - UI will hang forever..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed **Honza**'s advice (creating FormWithLabel from main UI thread) and redesigned my code as follows:

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormWithLabel splash = new FormWithLabel();
        //start long-term work in a separate thread
        new Task(() => { DoHeavyWork(splash); }).Start();
        //FormWithLabel will be closed at the end of DoHeavyWork task
        splash.ShowDialog(this);
    }

private void DoHeavyWork(FormWthLabel splash)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //checking whether FormWithHelp handle is already created to ensure 
            //that following Invoke will not throw InvalidOperationException
            while (!lScreen.IsHandleCreated)
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            //changing text inside a label on FormWithLabel (assuming label is public)
            splash.Invoke(new Action(() => { splash.label.Text = "Loading item №" + i; }));   
            //some heavy work emulation
            Thread.Sleep(1000);                             
        }
        //closing FormWithLabel and continuing main thread (showing fully filled main form)
        splash.Invoke(new Action(splash.Close));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `loadingForm` being null at Dispose it might be caused by fact that variable is not marked as `volatile`, but it is used from more threads. In which case compiler or runtime might decide do optimization (cache) of variable.

Comment: `loadingForm` static variable is used from Task and than from you main thread, that is were you create and started the task and you do Dispose of `loadingForm`.
Or maybe I just don't understand you fragment of code, so may be you could improve it?

Comment: I mean that `loadingForm` is not used from threads other that two described by you (main UI thread and Task's thread)

Comment: So you using it from more than one thread and that is causing your issue. It is also consistent with your discovery that if you change it into property behavior changes as it depends on complex optimizations. As mentioned earlier, consider redesign of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks is used when we donot want the application thread to lag or slow down due to intensive tasks.
Like in a javafx application we cannot use a thread directly we have to use task if we want to keep the ui free from lag and slowing down. And if you want to complete any task after thread has executed you have to use a listner like taskOnComplete or OnSucced.
This is the reason dispose is not getting called

For multiple tasks in parallel you can use Executor service.